# Find row with closest value down

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a shipping cost table with two dimensions: `Zone` and `Weight`.
`Zone` is an exact value. `Weight` is a range where given value is lower inclusive one. That means that in the given example, the highest range is 200-∞.

I am looking for a cost for given `Zone` and `Weight`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM fg.CostTest
WHERE Zone = 'A' AND Weight <= 123
ORDER BY Weight DESC
```

Having dozens of thousands rows in a table, is there a better way in terms of performance to achieve that?

I am using SQL Server 2022.

[image]

Comment: if you have an index on Zone, Weight with include on Cost, i doubt thousands rows will be a problem

Comment: Sure I do have an index covering mentioned columns. Seems that this is the fastest option as for now.

Answer (score 0):

this might help :

```
select * from (
   select *, row_number() over (order by abs(weight - 123)) rn
   from fg.CostTest
   where zone = 'A'
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: That works, however seems to be significantly slower than mine one. I compare these two with proper indexes in place.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making sure your columns zone and weight has index which would definitely help in the performance.

Then if the table is going to be used several times in queries or stored procedures, it’s best to create an indexed view that contains the LowerBoundWeight and Weight, and then use that view in queries as a join.

The View would be similar to the below:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_CostTest
AS
SELECT *, LAG(Weight,1,0) OVER (partition by Zone ORDER BY Weight) LowerBoundWeight
FROM CostTest;
```

Then on the select, join it as such

```
SELECT [COLUMNA_Names]
FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN vw_CostTest ct on t1.zone=ct.zone 
        AND t1.weight > ct.LowerBoundWeight
        AND t1.weight <= ct.weight
```

Answer (score 0):

Create procedure, it will help for repetition query:

Step 1 :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindCost]
    @Zone char(1),
    @Weight int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM costtest
    WHERE Zone = @Zone 
      AND Weight <= @Weight
    ORDER BY Weight DESC
```

Step 2: execute the stored procedure:

```
EXEC FindCost 'A', 123
```